# Импорт товаров в WordPress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, csv, импорт

При импорте csv идет проверка на существование изображений в uploads. Если файла нет, то ошибка. Failed to import 1 product. Error getting remote image /wp-content/uploads/image.jpg. Error: Not Found
Товар не импортируется, если не найдено изображение.
Можно отключить данную проверку?

Comment: Это не ошибка, а информация. Если файла нет - всего лишь его не будет в товаре. Всё остальное прекрасно импортируется.

Comment: @SeVlad, Failed to import 1 product. Error getting remote image /wp-content/uploads/7361.970qqq.jpg. Error: Not Found   Товар не импортируется, если не найдено изображение.

Comment: Это родной импорт? Хм.. У меня, помнится, импортировалось. Ну используй плагин.